# Парсинг json данных с конфигурации, php json

Tags: php, json

Входные данные:

```
config = 3
config_b.items = item1
config_b.items = item2
config_b.items.named_item = 123
config_c.root.a.b.c = 13
```

Как в итоге должно быть:

```
{"config":3,
 "config_b": {
   "items":{
     "0":"item1",
     "1":"item2",
     "named_item":123
   }
 }, "config_c": {
   "root": {
     "a": {
        "c":13
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Это то, что получилось у меня:

```
$input = '
config = 3
config_b.items = item1
config_b.items = item2
config_b.items.named_item = 123
config_c.root.a.b.c = 13';

$output = [];
$back_slash_exploded = explode("\n", $input);
foreach ($back_slash_exploded as $item) {
    if ($item) {
        $exploded = explode(' = ', $item);
        $dot_exploded = explode('.', $exploded[0]);

        $output[$dot_exploded[0]] = [];
        foreach ($dot_exploded as $new_key) {
            create_array($output, $new_key, $dot_exploded[0]);
        }
    }
}

function create_array(&$output, $new_key, $prev_key) {
    if (!isset($output[$new_key])) {
        foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == $prev_key) {
                $output[$prev_key][$new_key] = [];
            } else {
                create_array($output[$key], $new_key, $prev_key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

var_dump($output);

```
  array(3) {
  ["config"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["config_b"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["items"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["named_item"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["config_c"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["root"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["a"]=>
     array(0) {
    }
    ["b"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["c"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: почему не массив, а объект с числовыми ключами? зы: и чего там у вас не работает-то, мы сами должны проверить, или напишите все же?